# How to use a parameter or variable inside sql server statement using "if exist"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I'm making a stored procedure to create some columns based on existing one to make updates, what I need to do, is just replace the database name inside my statement [my_database] for a usable variable, it's this possible ?

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),@TABLE VARCHAR(MAX),@ENT VARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @DB_NAME = 'my_database'
SET @TABLE = 'TEST_db'
SET @ENT = 'Entidad'

IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM [my_database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE AND COLUMN_NAME = @ENT)
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'OK'
END
ELSE PRINT 'FAIL';
```

What I mean is the following. i want to Replace this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM [my_database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE AND COLUMN_NAME = @ENT)
```

for this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM DB_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE AND COLUMN_NAME = @ENT)
```

if there is a solution, please help me, i'm stuck :(

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL. Or use each database one at a time.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL; are you familiar with this concept? If you do a little poking around it should be easy enough to figure out, but in a nutshell you concatenate the query into an Nvarchar variable (so something like `Set @sql = 'Select column_name From [' + @DB_NAME + '].Information_Schema.Comuns'`) and then run `Exec sp_executeSQL @sql` and it should give you all the column_names from the Information_Schema.Columns table for the @DB_Name database. You can figure out the rest from there.

Comment: Is this a database-synchronisation job? Is the goal to find columns existing in one database in order to create them in the other one? If yes, there are great tools out there...

Comment: Tip: If you are going to use dynamic SQL you ought to read up a bit on "SQL injection". You can start with [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).